# .class == getClass() test fails

Tags: java, reflection, java.lang.class

Here's a small code I wrote to check the (is it called reflection API? not sure) classes at runtime, however I am not getting the intended results. Here is the code:

```
public class Outer {
    public Outer(){
        System.out.println("Outer Class");
    }
    public class Inner {
        public Inner(){         
            System.out.println("Inner Class");
        }
    }
}
```

Also here is the main function that I wrote to run the code and test it...

```
public class ClassTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Outer outObj = new Outer();
        Outer.Inner inObj = outObj.new Inner();

        // Using Reflection
        Class objTyp = inObj.getClass();
        System.out.println(objTyp.getName());

        //Testing Reflection
        if(objTyp.getClass() == Outer.Inner.class){
            System.out.println("Match classes!");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Mismatch classes!");
        }
    }
}
```

The test fails with the following error:

> if(objTyp.getClass() == Outer.Inner.class){
>                              ^   where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
>       CAP#1 extends Class from capture of ? extends Class 1 error

Please help me to correct the code. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: You should compare `Outer.Inner.class` with `objType`, not `objType.getClass()`.

Comment: @boxed__l `Outer.Inner.class` is a class literal so == should work.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle agreed ...getName() returns a String literal

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are comparing `Outer.Inner.class` with `objTyp.getClass()` instead of `objTyp`.

- `objTyp` is of type `Class<Outer.Inner>`.
- `objTyp.getClass()` is of type `Class<Class<Outer.Inner>>`.
- `Outer.Inner.class` is a class literal of type `Class<Outer.Inner>`.

Hence, `objTyp.getClass()` has no chance to equal `Outer.Inner.class`.

```
    Outer outObj = new Outer();
    Outer.Inner inObj = outObj.new Inner();

    // Using Reflection
    Class objTyp = inObj.getClass();
    System.out.println(objTyp.getName());

    //  >>>>> objTyp is already inObj.getClass() <<<<<<
    if(objTyp.getClass() == Outer.Inner.class){
        System.out.println("Match classes!");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Mismatch classes!");
    }
```

Comment: So doesn't `Class<Class<Outer.Inner>>` return the `Object` base class and test should fail printing `Mismatch classes!`?

Comment: It does not compile because you can't use == on objects of different types (`Class<Class<<Outer.Inner>>>` vs `Class<Outer.Inner>>`). You would have the same error trying to compare `List<String>` vs `List<Integer>`.